# flask run Error: While importing 'project', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, ubuntu-18.04

I have project directory named Project, and project directory includes python files and html files et al., and want to deploy in the AWS ec2 ubuntu sever.when I run in the local is ok.

when run "flask run" under the Project directory, there is error in the ubuntu terminal.

```
flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'project' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'project', an ImportError was raised
```

I have set a .flaskenv file as following:

```
FLASK_APP=project
FLASK_ENV=development
```

Comment: to get detailed import failures, invoke as: python app.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, reinstall all libraries again.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, there was an error in importing a specific library on FLASK_APP file. Running the command `python app.py` as [jluu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4698296/jluu) suggested will help you to know exactly when the ImportError happens.

Answer (score 2):

Did you installed your dependencies on your remote server? If yes, try installing your app as a module.

Given a the following directory structure:

```
/yourapplication
/yourApplicationMainFolder
    __init__.py
    /static
        style.css
    /templates
        layout.html
        index.html
        login.html
        ...
```

Create a `setup.py` file on `/yourapplication/setup.py` with:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='yourApplicationMainFolder',
    packages=['yourApplicationMainFolder'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
],)
```

Install with pip:

```
pip install -e .
```

If that did not work, comment out all your imports in the main script and inspect one by one to see which one is the problem.

Comment: I have done it, same error

Answer (score 2):

To future readers: something that might not be obvious is you can get more details on the import error by doing the following:

- Remove all import lines from your `__init__.py` file
- Run flask and navigate to the page it is hosted on
- ***While flask is running*** re-add the import lines to your `__init__.py` file and let flask update at run time
- Refresh the page in your browser.

You should now get more detailed information in the browser as to which line is causing the import error along with a traceback.